# ASP.NET MVC GET request with multiple optional filter query params

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing

Im trying to create a GET request that can handle few optional searching/filter params.

The request should look like:

https://localhost:99999/api/computers?ModelName=asus&RAM=2&ScreenSize=22

or

https://localhost:99999/api/computers?ModelName=asus&RAM=2

or

https://localhost:99999/api/computers?RAM=2&ScreenSize=22

or

https://localhost:99999/api/computers

The point is that it can have multiple optional params like: ModelName, RAM, ScreenSize or just  RAM, ScreenSize or ModelName, RAM or empty.

The conroller looks like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetComupters(string ModelName, int? RAM, int? ScreenSize)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

How should i build the RouteTemplate for this type of search\filtering?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enough a default route. You don't need anything extra for this. You can add attribute route.

```
 [HttpGet("~/api/computers")]
  public IHttpActionResult GetComupters(string ModelName, int? RAM, int? ScreenSize)
```

It was tested in net core and works properly.

But if you use old net version your register routes can be looking like this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);
 
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
 
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: “Default”,
        url: “api/{controller}/{action}/{id}”,
        defaults: new { controller = “Home”, action = “Index”, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried it but im getting 405 each time I try to lunch a request with less than those 3 params. getting 200 only with that : https://localhost:44390/api/computers?ModelName=asus&RAM=2&ScreenSize=3

Comment: getting 405 for --> https://localhost:44390/api/computers?ModelName=asus and https://localhost:44390/api/computers etc

Comment: @DavidAxelrod I tested it in net core using Postman and everything works properly. What  mvc version  and net version are you using?

Comment: The 405 Method Not Allowed is usually gives error if you use  post instead of get. How do you call this action? pls post your view

Comment: Hi im using the latest version of MVC
https://github.com/davidax0204/WebApiCRUD---Computers
Could you maybe please take a look maybe a did something wrong

Comment: here is a photo of my postman
https://ibb.co/JqMpy3y

Comment: I couldn't find any GetComupters there. And can you post the view where you call this action?

Comment: Here is a image of the postman: ibb.co/JqMpy3y And sorry, The GetComputers is located at Controllers/Api/ComputerController

Comment: @DavidAxelrod Try to move it to Controllers folder  and and [HttpGet("~/api/computers")] attribute

Comment: Thanks!!! it worked